# How to send data from controller blade to component livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, livewires

People who know LIVEWIRE-LARAVEL ‼ I need to get some code working on livewire ( form update )
I'm trying to pass data (products)
:From controller ( layout content )
To a livewire component (product-update)

But it doesn't work, sometimes it doesn't recognize "$products" sometimes it sends forms doesn't work from livewire component

So what is good practice? To retrieve product data and make form update work from livewire

Thanks in advance

controller that call livewire component (as suugested by KeyvanGholami):

```
public function editProduit($idsscatg, $idprd){

    $ss_catg = SousCategorie::find($idsscatg);

    $idsscatgg = $idsscatg;
    $idprdd = $idprd;

    $nom_catg = $ss_catg->nom_catg;

    if( $ss_catg->nom_catg == 'Consommable médico-chirurgical')
    {
        $produit = ProduitConsommable::find($idprdd);
        
        return view('livewire.update-produit',compact('produit', 'idsscatgg', 'nom_catg'));

    }
```

my component (update-produit) inorder to test the submiting for,
BUT THE FORM DOENS'T SUBMIT !!! it reload and return back the form with the token in url:

```
@extends('Admin.layoutAdmin')
@section('content')
{{-- <livewire:update-produit :produits="$produits")> --}}
<div>
    <div class="container-fluid mb-5">
        <div class="row mb-4">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <h3> Modifier Produit </h3>
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <form class="contact-form row" wire:submit.prevent="oui" enctype = "multipart/form-data">                       
                @csrf
                <input type="text" wire:model="oui">
                <div class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" >                         
                    <button wire:click="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>

                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

livewire function pour test form submit:

```
public function mount(){

        $cons = SousCategorie::where('nom_catg', 'Consommable médico-chirurgical')->get();
        $equips = SousCategorie::where('nom_catg', 'Equipements')->get();
        $mobs = SousCategorie::where('nom_catg', 'Mobilier médical')->get();
        $landangers = SousCategorie::where('nom_catg', 'Landanger')->get();
        $delacroixs = SousCategorie::where('nom_catg', 'Delacroix-chevalier')->get();
        $divs = SousCategorie::where('nom_catg', 'Divers')->get();

                 
        View::share('cons', $cons);
        View::share('equips', $equips);
        View::share('mobs', $mobs);
        View::share('landangers', $landangers);
        View::share('delacroixs', $delacroixs);
        View::share('divs', $divs);

    }
    public function render($produits)
    {
        return view('livewire.update-produit');   
    }


    public function oui(){

        $oui = $this->oui;
        dd($oui);

    }
```

Help me please !

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: i added the code to the question, please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never touch laravel controller whenever using livewire since it has their own Class for that. If you want to retrieve Product data, Just make a livewire component and Pass it through view. Something like this (sorry its horrible)

**ProductIndex.php**

```php
...
protected $listeners = ['productUpdated'];

public function productUpdated() {
  // Just Blank
}

public function render() {
  return view('your-livewire-product-index', ['products' => Product::all());
}
```

**Blade product Index**

```html
<div>
  <ul>
     @foreach($products as $product) {
       <li>{{ $product->name }} | <a href="{{ route('products.edit', ['product' => $product->id]) }}">Edit</a></li>
     @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
```

This for update

**ProductEdit.php**

```php
...
public $name, $product_id;
public Product $product;

public function mount() {
  $getProductID = explode('/', url()->current());
  $this->product_id = end($getProductID);
}

public function update() {
   // For simplicity i just update product name
   Product::find($this->product_id)->update(['name' => $this->name]);

   // I call event so ProductIndex listen it and it will auto update the productIndex list
   $this->emit('productUpdated');
}

public function render() {
   return view('livewire-edit-product', ['product' => Product::find($this->product_id)]);
}
```

**Blade product Edit**

```html
<div>
  <form wire:submit.prevent="update">
    <input type="hidden" wire:model="product_id">
    <input type="text" wire:model="name">
    <input type="submit" value="save">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the LiveWire component in the controller view (blade file) and pass the data (products) through it.

Comment: hI, i did it but le form does't submit ( it reload and returd back)

Comment: i added the code to the question, please help me. Thank you

Comment: You specified here `wire:submit.prevent="oui"` that the registered form oui should be called `, where is this method?
You also wrote here `wire:click="submit"` that the form button calls the submit method, where is this method?
The codes are inconsistent.

Comment: its better to refactor codes in this way:
`<form class="contact-form row" wire:submit.prevent="submit" enctype = "multipart/form-data">                       
                @csrf
                <input type="text" wire:model="oui">
                <div class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" >                         
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>

                </div>
            </form>`
but dont forget write submit method

Comment: the method oui  is in livewire component, juste after render ().                                           public function oui(){

        $oui = $this->oui;
        dd($oui);

    }                                                                                                                                    i was thinking that : wire:submit.prevent="oui" call method "oui" in livewire ?!

Comment: Okay. But there is still no submit method! `wire:click="submit"`

Comment: yes i should put type="submit".

Comment: when you said to call the LiveWire component in the controller view (blade file) and pass the data (products) through it . That is what i had done with here, that's right ?                                                                                                                                   
 return view('livewire.update-produit',compact('produit', 'idsscatgg', 'nom_catg'));

Comment: Even with juste type='submit' button, same think doen't even detect methoc 'oui' which is in livewire :(

Comment: See, the easiest way I can tell you is to call the livewire directly via route instead of calling controller. ok?

Comment: In the previous case, you have to change this part:`        return view('livewire.update-produit',compact('produit', 'idsscatgg', 'nom_catg'));
` and in view blade file that belongs to controller call uour live wire component like this:`<livewire:update-produit .....">`

Comment: Okey sorry but i don't understand what you mean, i know it's complicate to understand what i want to do. i have layoutAdmin with @yield('content') , in this content i want to use component livewire. how can i get this component livewire here !? Really sorrrrryyy for disturbance